# Get app info with Apple Store Connect API

Tags: python, app-store-connect

I'm researching a way to get data from a specific app on the Apple Store with Apple Store Connect API, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding a solution.

Has anyone been able to get app information from the Apple Store? Maybe even get with Python? Example: Ratings, number of downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://gist.github.com/corrieriluca/3c9f062401582dad83013d7363741b0c).

The main idea is you are going to get yourself `KEY_ID`, `ISSUER_ID` and `PATH_TO_KEY` if you haven't already, then make a REST call with those in the headers and payload, as the requests require a bearer token.

EDIT:
Also I am assuming this app is yours, as of writing I cannot find explicit reference in their documentation to scraping information from apps other than your own, as it targets automating workflows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/read_app_information.